# Kolmogorov's 0-1 Law related : proving that $\mathbb{P} \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}=1 \right) = 1$

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

Letting $\lbrace X_n \rbrace$ be a sequence of independent real valued random variables and supposing that  $$\mathbb{P}\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}=1 \right) \gt 0,$$
I'm trying to prove that $$\mathbb{P} \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}=1 \right) = 1.$$
That makes me think about the Kolomogorov's 0-1 Law but I can't show that the event $$\lbrace \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}=1 \rbrace$$
is a tail event (that is that it lies in $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \sigma \lbrace  X_i:i \geq n\rbrace$).

Am I on the right track? Could you help me complete this, I'm confused!

Comment: *Hint*: As long as each $X_i$ are a.s.-finite, then for any $m$, we have $$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{n} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_{m} + \cdots + X_n}{n} $$ and likewise for liminf. Thus we can ignore finitely many terms without affecting the convergence.

Comment: Since my random variables are real valued, they are a.s.-finite, right?  I think I see from the definitions of $lim sup$ and $lim inf$ why that result is true! though I'm not sure how to conclude... Can I say $\lbrace \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n} =1 \rbrace$ is the intersection of lim sup being 1 and lim inf being 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. The only thing you need to prove is that $A = \left[\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{n} = 1\right]$ is a tail event.

For each **fixed** $m$, observe that
\begin{align}
& \left[\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{n} = 1\right] \\
= & \left[\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_{m - 1} + X_m + \cdots + X_n}{n} = 1\right] \\
= &\left[\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_m + \cdots + X_n}{n} = 1\right] \in \sigma(X_m, X_{m + 1}, \ldots),
\end{align}
in view of $X_1 + \cdots + X_{m - 1}$ is a fixed random variable.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Are you implicitly using $lim sup$s? I'm not sure I understand the last simplification...

Comment: No $\limsup$ is needed. If $\lim (X_1 + \cdots + X_n)/n$ exists, since $\lim (X_1 + \cdots + X_m)/n = 0$ (consider it pointwisely), $\lim (X_m + \cdots + X_n)/n$ also exists.

Comment: Oooh! I see! Thank you so much!!